# Express solution set to the matrix equation Ax = B in form p + span(B) where p is a specified solution to the equation and B is a basis for null(A)?

Tags: matrices

```
I'm given A = 1  1  1  1  0
              1  2  1  1  1
              2  3  3  1  1
              4  6  5  3  2

And B = 1
        1
        4 
        6
```

I use B as the augmented column and after getting my row reduced echelon form of

```
1  0  0  2  -1 | -1 
0  1  0  0   1 | 0 
0  0  1  -1  0 | 2 
0  0  0  0   0 | 0
```

I'm not sure how else to proceed with this problem. My teacher doesn't explain things in depth so I'm always coming online to find out how to do these.

My apologies for not knowing how to input matrices yet. I hope this suffices.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this equation: $Ax = 0$. Suppose you have two solutions $v, w$.

That means $Av = 0, Aw = 0$, which in turn means $A(v+w) = Av + Aw = 0$, which means $v+w$ is also a solution. Also, $A(\alpha v) = \alpha Av = 0$ so scaling a solution gives a solution.

Now imagine $z$ is a solution of $Ax = b$; that is $Az = b$. Notice how $z+v, z+w$ are also solutions of $Ax = b$. Can you show why? Also, suppose $z_1, z_2$ are solutions of $Ax = b$. Can you show that $z_1 - z_2$ is a solution of $Ax = 0$? That is why, often to solve $Ax = b$, we just find one specific solution $p$, and then solve $Ax = 0$ instead (which is the same as finding the nullity of $A$). If $\mathcal{N}(A)$ is the nullity of $A$ and $p$ is a specific solution, then the solutions of $Ax = b$ are precisely $p + \mathcal{N}(A)$.

Using the step you are at, you should be able to find a specific solution to the equation $Ax = b$. After that, just compute the nullity of $A$ (using the reduced echelon form you have) and find a basis for it.

Because the nullity of a matrix is a vector space, you can find a basis for it. Can you understand, from the row reduced echelon form you have, that the nullity will have dimension $1$? That means you only need to find a non-zero vector $v$ in the nullity, and then $\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{L}(v)$.